# Pivot Tables grand total

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

The "Grand Total" in my Pivot Table does not reflect a (red) negative amount for a deficit year.  All Grand Totals for the 5 years show a positive amount.  How do I change the formatting or need to do so that the Grand Total will show (red) negative for the deficit year, and a positive number for a surplus year?
Appreciate any and all suggestions.  Thank you.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

The Grand Total row uses the same Number Format as each of its respective values.

You set the Number Format for the value to have it reflected in the Grand Total.

Right-click the Value name in Pivot Table (i.e. where it says 'Sum of Sales' in my example) and select 'Number Format'. Select the desired format.

[image: picture]